# Find the simplest annihilator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the simplest annihilator for $R(s) = (e^s+\cos(s))(e^s+\sin(s))$.

I keep getting lost in my work. I don’t know if I’m just over complicating it.

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Jason?

Comment: Not polite to ask a question, Jason, and then disappear.

Answer (score 2):

$(e^s+\cos s)(e^s+\sin s)=e^{2s}+e^s(\cos s+\sin s)+\sin s\cos s$. Writing $D$ for the differential operator, $e^{2s}$ is annihilated by $D-2$, $e^s(\cos s+\sin s)$ is annihilated by $D^2-2D+2$, and $\sin s\cos s=(1/2)\sin2s$ is annihilated by $D^2+4$. So the answer is the product of these, $(D-2)(D^2-2D+2)(D^2+4)$.

Comment: Are you *the* Gerry Myerson? https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson

Comment: Yes. Somehow I lost access to that account.